# Jira : Where do the Search filter appear on the Shared person's board

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I created a search filter through Click Issues->Search for issues, in Jira and shared it with the developer group.

Now I am not aware where has the developer navigate to view the filter. Can someone give me that general path on which the search filter which is shared to the person or group can view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways they can get to the filter:

On the menu at the top, select `Filters`. The second item from the bottom is `View all filters` and the filter you created will be on that page.

The other way to reach it is by clicking on the cog icon that gets you into settings. Select `System` from the menu and then scroll the list on the left down until you reach `Shared filters`. Again, the filter you created will be on that page.